# Multi-language GUI setup with a string array

Tags: c, embedded

I am working on the Keil uv4 IDE with an ARM Cortex-M3 in a bare metal C application. I have a GUI that I created that is currently in English, but I would like to give the user the ability to go between other languages like you can on a cell phone.

I have created a structure with all the words that are used called string_table_t.

```
struct string_table_t
{
    char *word1;
    char *word2;
    char *word3;
};
```

My thought process was to have plain text files for the different languages and the list of words used contained in each one. Then I would do a load function that would link the pointers of the string table with the actual word.

Now, my initial menu is created statically by defining it like so. It is based off of Altium software platform.

```
// Test structure
struct string_table_t string_table = {"Main Menu","test1","test2"};

form_t mainmenu_form =
{
    .obj.x = 0,
    .obj.y = 0,
    .obj.width = 240,
    .obj.height = 320,
    .obj.draw = form_draw,
    .obj.handler = mainmenu_form_handler,
    .obj.parent = NULL,
    .obj.agui_index = 0,
    .obj.visible = __TRUE,
    .obj.enabled = __TRUE,
    .caption.x = 0,
    .caption.y = 0,
    .caption.text = "Main Menu",
    .caption.font = &helveticaneueltstdltext18_2BPP,
    .caption.color = RGB(230,230,230),
    .caption_line_color = RGB(241,101,33),
    .caption.fontstyle = FS_NONE,
    .caption.align = ALIGN_CENTRE,
    .captionbarcolor = RGB(88,89,91),
    .children = mainmenu_children,
    .n_children = 4,
    .relief = RELIEF_NONE,
    .color = RGB(65,64,66),
};
```

What I want to do is replace the "Main Menu" of the caption.text with string_table.word1. Therefore, if I load a different language set, the menu will automatically be pointing to the correct char array. Doing this currently results in a error expression must have a constant value.

Now, I can get this to work by leaving the text null in the menu component and adding:

```
Link_pointer_to_menu() {
    mainmenu_form.caption.text = string_table.Main_menu_text;
}
```

This will compile and work, but I would rather not have to have 100 or so of these statements. Is there a more optimal way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend something like that:

```
enum MyWords
{
    msgHello,
    msgOpen,
    msgClose,
    msgMainMenu,
    num_Messages,
};

char *string_table_t[num_Messages];
```

You should write code that loads your language file and assigns pointers in this array. After that in your code:

```
.caption.text = string_table_t[msgMainMenu];
```

The idea is that you give each string a symbolic name that is an offset in the table of strings. After that you use this offset as an index into the table.

Comment: `.caption.text = string_table_t[msgMainMenu];` Must be done in a function though it can't be done statically when I declare the rest of the parameters of the menu.

Comment: Once you init your struct with pointers at runtime, you cannot pick values of the pointers from there before the language specific initilization.

Comment: Ah, I see I have no choice then but to create a function that goes through every menu location and assigns its caption.text to the correct offset in the table.